# Is it possible to turn on Site Collection auditing programmatically using CSOM/JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm creating sites/site collections using CSOM (client code) via an autohosted App. I need to turn on site auditing but can't seem to find any way to do this programmatically.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In CSOM API v. `16.1.3912.1204` was introduced support for Audit management.

Following code example shows how to enable all auditing setting in site collection level and how to adjust audit log trimming.

```
var site = clientContext.Site;
var audit = site.Audit;
clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.Load(audit);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
// Enable all auditing is site collection level
site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.All;
site.Audit.Update();
// Adjust retention time to be 7 days
site.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 7;
site.TrimAuditLog = true;
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Follow [PnP/Samples/Core.Settings.Audit](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/710f9a37ffdffd18acc341f48eff0069fa101d2a/Samples/Core.Settings.Audit) for a more details.

Download the latest version of CSOM SDK from [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) or via NuGet `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM`